# Etag Configuration in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, etag

When a **Status Code:304 Not Modified** is being returned by the service.
(Which mean a resource is not modified.) then why the response is seen in the network call being sent (Checked in chrome networktab)?

The following code is added for a shallow etag.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>  
<filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Is the response that you're seeing in Chrome a 200 or a 304?

Comment: I am seeing it as 304 in network tab but still i could see the response.

Comment: You mean you're seeing a response body when the server returns a 304?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it.

In Network tab when 304 response comes,the data is retrieved from cache.

Confirmed it by the size of bytes transferred during a **200** request and **304** request.

There is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the client(browser) you use has cached the response locally. What you see the with 304 after request is still the local response, indicating that the response is not gained again from the server.